# How to install pycaret on Python 3.10?

Tags: python, python-3.10, pycaret

I am trying to install pycaret and it's showing below error:

```
 customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
   
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/f6/75297be19f48b7a8c2577753a3a700f98fc4db49d0e5ed3820dd8dee43d4/scikit-learn-0.23.2.tar.gz#sha256=20766f515e6cd6f954554387dfae705d93c7b544ec0e6c6a5d8e006f6f7ef480 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-0rixacmy\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6uf_b86o\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\HP\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32\\pywintypes39.dll'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I have tried to re-install and still not working, it keeps showing the same error as indicated above.

Comment: what `pip` command you used?

Comment: !pip install pycaret

Answer (score 0):

Error says 2 things. `No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler'`  module is missing & also permission warning. What command you uisng inorder to install `pycaret`.

Install numpy again if not installed,

```
pip install numpy --user
```

Then

Official pypi - [pypi - pycaret](https://pypi.org/project/pycaret/)

```
pip install pycaret --user
```

If both deosn't work it will be issue with Microsoft build tools. [visual studio dist packages:](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12016#issuecomment-555354320)

Answer (score 0):

The current version of pycaret (2.3.10) does not support Python 3.10.
The next version of pycaret (3.0.0) will support Python 3.10.

To install the pre-release version of 3.0.0, you can use the following

```
pip install -U --pre pycaret
```